# Power to panel in mobile home

Tags: electrical

I have 60 amps coming from main shut off on pole to my mobile home which has a 125 amp rated panel with a 100 amp main breaker in it. My question is, can I have the 60 amps increased to 100 or 125 amps to match my home main panel?
Problem I currently have is that lights dim when fridge or electric dryer pull demand.

Comment: Can we have the square footage of your house, and what you have for a HVAC system for that matter?  Also, what gauge is the wire coming from the pole to the house, and is it an overhead or an underground line?

Comment: Adding on to @ThreePhaseEel, you will also need to contact your electric utility company and submit a service request. Whenever you increase your panel or load, the utility company needs to know to make sure their equipment can handle it. They'll check wire size, their own circuit protection, etc.

Comment: **You have an electrical *problem***.  If you upgrade service, you will have upgraded service and your lights will still dim because  you still have an electrical problem.  I would fix the problem instead of upgrading the service.  Not upgrading the service won't burn your house down, the problem sure might.

Comment: To clarify a bit, unless you're tripping breakers now, upgrading the service *panel* and related breakers won't do anything. Breakers don't limit current. They just trip when there's an overload with respect to their rating.

Answer (score 3):

First let's look at your situation where you have a 60A Service Disconnect and a 100A main breaker in your panel. You should never have a larger amperage breaker after a smaller trip breaker because if you have a fault downstream, the service disconnect will trip prior to your main breaker. So your main breaker is ineffective and is only being used as an equipment disconnect.

Second: **Yes you can increase your service disconnect size but only if your feeder conductors to your panel are the correct size** to handle the updated overcurrent protection.

Third: Your dimming may be caused by your service feeder being undersized and is causing a voltage drop to unacceptable levels or it may be caused by a broken neutral or ground. I would have that checked first before going to the expense of replacing a service.

Hope this helps and good luck.